# Translation of "I have a feeling..."

Tags: traducción

What's the best way to translate "I have a feeling..."

This is not feeling as in feeling happy/sad etc, but instead more of an instinct/idea/guess.

Eg.

> I have a feeling that someone here knows the answer to this. =)

Thanks =)

Comment: The problem with your example is that "I have a feeling" is more of the idiomatic usage for "I think" rather than actually having a premonition about something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would translate *to have a feeling* as *presentir*; here's the definition from the DRAE:

> [presentir](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltObtenerHtml?origen=RAE&LEMA=presentir&SUPIND=0&CAREXT=10000&NEDIC=No).
>
> (Del lat. praesentīre).
>
> 1. tr. Intuir, tener la sensación de que algo va a suceder.
> 2. tr. Adivinar algo antes que suceda, por algunos indicios o señales que lo preceden.

Your concrete example:

> I have a feeling that someone here knows the answer to this.

would be

> Presiento que alguien aquí sabe la respuesta.

As Laura has suggested in a comment, another commonly used translation would be *Me parece que*; in this case,

> I have a feeling that someone here knows the answer to this.

would be

> Me parece que alguien aquí sabe la respuesta.

Another possibility for *to have a feeling* would be *intuir* as in *Intuyo que alguien aquí sabe la respuesta*, but I would opt for *presentir*.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina At least in Spain we use a lot "Me parece que..."

Comment: @Laura I agree--I think that's more common and fits the translation  closely enough, even though it's not a direct translation. You might consider using "Me parece que..." if the translation should sound natural. My Spanish is from Mexico.

Comment: @Laura: you're aboslutely right ;-) I've updated my answer to reflect your comment. Thank you!

Comment: This post has reminded me that sentence heard in the Star Wars saga movies: `I have a bad feeling ···`, which was translated as `Tengo un mal presentimiento`.

Answer (score 6):

I would translate it to

> Tengo la sensación

So your sentence can be translated to:

> Tengo la sensación de que alguien aquí sabe la respuesta.

[Here](http://www.linguee.es/espanol-ingles/search?source=auto&query=tengo+la+sensaci%F3n) you can see more examples of "tengo la sensación" with the corresponding English sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context, you could also translate it as "sospecho," as in "I suspect."

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a very idiomatic expression (used and understood at least in Spain), I would say:

> **Me da [a mí] que** alguien conoce la respuesta a esta pregunta.

It's just an abbreviation of "me da la sensación de que...". The "a mí" part is optional, you can add it for emphasis.

If you look "[dar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BrtRK35)" up in the dictionary, the meaning I am referring to is:

> 30. tr. Presagiar, anunciar.